Is my approach to compute Granger causality valid?
I have two time-series, let us call them A (colored in red) and B (colored in blue). There are ~770 data points per time-series.
Note: Both time-series are in fact not the recorded raw signals, but they are the outcome of a sliding window approach. I applied the exact same sliding window approach on both original raw time-series, and then computed a measurement for each window. This allows me to compare the temporal evolution or structure of that measurement for both signals.
Problem: While the two raw or original time-series are stationary, the outcome of the sliding window approach is not. As can be seen easily from the plot, the sliding window time-series are non-stationary (and they of course fail the ADF and KPSS tests).
Aim: I would like to compute if B (blue) granger causes A (red), hence applying a Granger causality test. Now, let us move the issue if it coneptually makes sense to apply Granger causality between two sliding window based time-series aside. Let us assume both time-series stem from non-stationary raw signals. I followed the Toda and Yamamoto (1995) approach to compute Granger causality as explained in this link for Python:
https://rishi-a.github.io/2020/05/25/granger-causality.html
Here is a plot for which I would like to test Granger causality. The shown p-value p < 0.001 is computed after taking the first difference of each time-series, making them stationary. The p-value after differencing stems from ssr_chi2test test, and the optimal lag was based on the BIC criterion. (In fact, even without differencing, the p-value remains p < 0.001.) The differenced time-series pass the ADF and KPSS tests and they also look perfectly stationary.

Here is the same plot after differencing both time-series (first difference). It is on these time-series upon which the granger causality test is performed following all steps of the link above.

Questions: I have several questions.

Given that the time-series are based on sliding windows, is it valid to manually select a lag of one (also given the assumption that the impact of B on A happens almost without a time lag anyway)?

Is differencing both time-series to make them stationary due to their extreme erratic temporal structure absolutely necessary before testing for Granger causality, or would it be valid to compute Granger causality without differencing because the non-stationary time-series reflect the real temporal evolution of the measurement?
Update: Question 2 requires more clarification. The origin of both time-series is different. One sliding window time-series comes from brain activity, and the other time-series comes from an auditory input. The Spearman correlation between both time-series is ~0.8 before differencing. The correlation is ~0 after differencing. The shared information (correlation) between both time-series rests on the multiple trends across time, and it is not found in a time point to time point matching. The fact that the high correlation is driven by shared trends is not surprising, given the complete different nature of both time-series signals. Phrased differently, the best we can hope for is to see shared trends in the sliding window results from both time-series (which, as we can see, was a correct prediction). Given the aforementioned, should I still difference before computing GC, or do I throw out essential information of both sliding window time-series by differencing in my case?

Based on a visual inspection of the original (non-differenced) time-series, would you rather recommend a complete different approach to compute Granger causality than the one described in the link that I followed?


As a beginner to Granger causality and the VAR model, I generally wonder if the approach and code in the link I cited (https://rishi-a.github.io/2020/05/25/granger-causality.html) generally suits my specific data, or if I am doing something that is really flawed.

To me the graphs do not suggest the series contain unit roots. They do not wander off indefinitely but tend to return to the same level. There is a temporary increase in the level of the blue series around time periods 75-225, so perhaps something happened there, but that was temporary.

The ADF test for the red graph returns statistic = -2.79 and p-value = 0.058.  For the blue graph it is statistic = -1.73 and p-value = 0.413. (The ADF statistics just mentioned are before differencing.) As I understand it, this means that the data is non-stationary and requires a method to make it stationary (such as differencing) before computing GC. For the VAR I use the original (non-differenced) time-series and for the final GC test, I use the differenced time-series (both as described in the link above). Refering to my question 2, am I doing it "right"?

The test results are such that you cannot reject $H_0$ of presence of a unit root. We cannot be sure whether that is because $H_0$ is true or $H_1$ is true but the test is not powerful enough to learn that. Looking at the graphs, my guess is the latter. On the other hand, if a series is close to containing a unit root, differencing it is not big mistake, so you are probably fine doing that. My favorite treatment of the Toda-Yamamoto procedure is the one by Daves Giles. I would follow it.

Richard, is it ok to only difference one of the two time-series, or would that be very bad for computing GC? Phrased differently, if one (of the two) time-series requires differencing, then should I always difference both time-series?

As a rule of thumb, you should not difference a time series that does not contain a unit root. So if you are dealing with a pair of series where one is I(1) and the other is I(0), do not difference the latter one.

Thank you for your help Richard, your answers are MUCH appreciated by me.

Thank you for the kind words! It is rewarding to know some of my efforts have been found useful.

Dear Richard, I added substantially more information to my second question above in the original post. I would love to hear your opinion on this in case you have one.

I do not fully understand the matter, so it is hard for me to recommend this or that. I am not sure if the question is statistical (what is the correct use of the tools such as GC) or pertaining to the subject matter (what should be investigated).
